# Angular bootstrap modal is resetting the child views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to angular and have a situation where we have nested views and one of the view has link(s) to open a modal

But the issue is that when the modal opens up one of the views in the background is getting reset..dont know why and how can we resolve it?

[Plnkr][1] : 
http://embed.plnkr.co/dliyNd5EaobgkFNA8Xxg/

will really appriciate the help..

so the issue if if we open child1 on the page and then click on open modal it actually clears the child 1 view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a `home.modal1` state, and trying to **redirect** to it by `ui-sref` in `view2.html`. As it didn't have a `template` to show, so you will see a blank page which looks like the child views are resetted.

I have add a `template` for `home.modal1` state with your [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZYdRu3VWPCfgtL3BtxGX?p=preview) to help you confirm that.

---

You can change the `ui-sref` to `ng-click` and define a function in `view2.html` **controller** which calls the `$modal.open` to open the modal.

Comment: I actually tried this already but made a mistake..by putting the href as '#' too.. that was causing the page to change to go to intial state and i though it has something to do with the way ui states work...removing the '#' and just keepint it empty with ng-click did the trick...thanks